# Creating a text view on every button click

Tags: android

I am trying to create a text view on button click , so that each time I press the button a new text view is created.

The problem: I am only getting single textview created, because when I am pressing the button again nothing is created.

The code:

```
//In a class I defined a button
 Button button;

//I set the button to on click listener

button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener{
@override
public void onClick(View view){
//now I want to create text view dynamically
TextView textview= new TextView(myactivity.this);
textview.setText("new text");

//the problem is that this method helps me make only one text I want to 
// create text view each time the button pressed.


}
});
```

thanks

edit: I didnt forget about setting the view in the layout and giving it parameters, I cant find the problem, I generate one textview no matter what I do

Comment: you are doing it wrong, you are just replacing textview with old one

Comment: @Divyesh can you give a solution please?

Comment: wait for some time

Comment: checkkkkkkkkkkk

Answer (score 0):

First add layout where you want to add textview in xml:

```
        <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/anything"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"/>
        </LinearLayout>
```

Now in Activity:

```
      LinearLayout lin;
      lin = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.anything);
      lin.removeAllViews();

button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener{
@override
public void onClick(View view){

     TextView txtName = new TextView(MainActivity.this);
     txtName.setId(28);
     txtName.setText("new text");

     lin.addView(txtName);

}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Currently, your code is just replacing your old textview with a new one.

To fix this, get the layout in which you want the TextView to show up from your layout.xml.

Then add your TextView to that Layout like this:

```
LinearLayout mLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.mLayout);
Button bn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
bn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
   public void onClick(View v) {
       TextView tv1 = new TextView(MainActivity.this);
       tv1.setText("Show Up");
       mLayout.addView(tv1);
        }   
});
```

Comment: why did you use getApplicationContext() and not Activity.this.

Comment: Thanks, fixed it now.

Answer (score 0):

create xml,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/llTextviews"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical" >
        </LinearLayout>
        <Button android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello, I am a Button" />
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

in java class,

```
LinearLayout layout;
LinearLayout linearlayout = new LinearLayout(ACTIVITY);

LayoutParams LLParams = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT_PARENT);
linearlayout .setLayoutParams(LLParams);

layout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.llTextviews);

button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener{
@override
public void onClick(View view){

    layout.removeAllViews();

    TextView txtName = new TextView(MainActivity.this);
    txtName.setId(28);
    txtName.setText("new text");

    linearlayout.addView(txtName);
    layout.addView(linearLayout);

    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to dynamically generate View Id use form API 17

[generateViewId()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#generateViewId%28%29)

Like this

```
@Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                EditText editText = new EditText(MainActivity.this);
                editText.setId(editText.generateViewId());
                editText.setHeight(50);
                editText.setWidth(50);
                ll.addView(editText);

            }

private EditText editText(String hint) {
                EditText editText = new EditText(this);
                editText.setId(Integer.valueOf(hint));
                editText.setHint(hint);
                editTextList.add(editText);
                return editText;
            }
```